# Streaming an mp4 with php

Tags: php, video, streaming, mp4, protected

I am looking for a way to stream the contents from a mp4-file to mediaelement - the problem here is that I need to make sure that people who access the files are logged in - and they must not be able to easily decode the url and post it elsewhere.

I've got the login system taken care of - just not sure how to combine it with streaming an mp4.

I have been searching around and have yet to find any soulutions, unfortunatly. 
All ideas are welcome.

Regards,
Anders

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is mediaelement?

Comment: This is mediaelement: http://mediaelementjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

A quick search has yielded this result for me:
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Video-Streaming-PHP-Script-Tutorial/

I see no need to write out what it says, just read it there. I'll expand on it here however.
Once you've got your script fully working (streaming) then you implement the authentication methods. To do this you'll probably want to include your login checking script and check whether they're logged in or not - if they aren't logged in then just do something like `die('authentication error');`.

Then, if you place all the videos in a single sub-directory, you could use a `.htaccess` rule to completely stop users accessing videos directly! (not that they could realistically find the real URL anyway).

This does not stop users downloading to share your videos - but it would mean they had to be logged in to watch them (like you want). As for downloading to share; perhaps a watermark?

Comment: How would you suggest I use htaccess to prevent access to the videos? I know a bit of htaccess, but its primarily related to rewriting and caching.

Comment: This should do it for you: http://www.techiecorner.com/1245/how-to-block-access-to-certain-file-types-using-htaccess/

Comment: Almost there. My new problem is that it looks like im not sending the correct headers.  header('Content-type: video/mp4');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size
  header("Expires: -1");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);

Comment: Because it dosn't start when using any kind of player except when I access it directly it downloads it.

Comment: I'm not great with headers, so I'm not sure if that's the problem or not - but there's a lot of headers you can use just here: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/headers.htm this one: `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` stands out to me.